# In what directory to put java libraries for maven project?

Tags: java, maven

I found that Maven implies specific directory layout. But I don't understand from here: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html
where java libraries needed to compile and run my code should be placed. I think they shouldn't be placed under 'src/main/resources' because resources is something like images or so. Also it doesn't look right to place them under 'src/main/java'. If I wouldn't use maven, I'd place libraries in project's root `lib` directory. But I don't think that for maven project it will be right. Please advise.

UPD: I solved the problem. The matter was that I set packages for my sources as src.main.myApp instead of main.myApp. This seems to upset maven.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maven handles your project dependencies in a different way to a 'Standard' Java project.

You declare the libraries you depend on in your project's pom.xml:

e.g.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>your-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>your-project-web</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>     
</project>
```

When you use a maven command to build the project, i.e. `mvn install`, it will download the dependencies for you and store them in your local repository.

Comment: I got it. But shouldn't IDE have that libraries, so I can develop and compile my sources inside an IDE without unsatisfied links or smth?

Comment: You can use the maven plugin for eclipse, that will parse your pom.xml and automatically download the libraries for you and update your project build path.

Comment: Should I have maven installed locally, or is it sufficient to have an eclipse with maven-plugin?

Comment: Both, Maven installed locally allows you to run maven builds from the command line, the maven eclipse plugin allows your IDE to understand your pom.xml and keep your project synced with the pom.

Comment: I created a maven project in eclipse, added dependencies to pom.xml, but still my sources that are using external libraries are marked as error.

Comment: You can also use the maven-eclipse-plugin found here http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/

This is a plugin to maven, to allow maven to build your eclipse .classpath and .project files.  Read through thes docs at the above URL about how to add it to your pom, then use the command `mvn eclispe:eclipse` from the command line in your project's root directory.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9206/discussion-between-gasan-and-evil-raat)

Answer (score 1):

In Maven, you do not keep libraries in your project. You specify dependencies on these libs, and they get populated into your local repository. At the time of build, if you are packaging the libs (say for a war file), they do get pulled into  target//WEB-INF/lib. But in general, the whole idea is not to deal with these libraries or manage them, just to manage dependencies in your pom file, and forget the rest.